# ScrollMagic pin changes initial Y position of pinned element

Tags: javascript, css, scrollmagic

I'm working on a web page with a navbar. This navbar has two divs, one for the logo and another for the menu. Both divs are initially at the same Y position, but when I try to pin the menu div, it changes its initial Y position to down.

why? Thank you in advance!

I've isolated the problem in a codepen:
http://codepen.io/aitormendez/pen/NbvpXj

Removing JS of the codepen, menu div becomes at the initial Y position.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <header class="banner">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-brand-container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><div class="logo-int">Logo</div></a>
    </div><div class="menu-1">
    <p>Menu 1</p>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
  // Pin menu-1
  var pinM1Scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: '.menu-1',
    triggerHook: 0
  })
  .setPin('.menu-1')
  .addTo(controller);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it. The automatic inserted `div.scrollmagic-pin-spacer` has a `display: inline-block`. So, I tell it to align to top:

```
.scrollmagic-pin-spacer {
      vertical-align: top;
    }
```